# Alguém sabe como é possível no postgresql, tenho duas tabelas com coluna tipo ARRAY e o usar o WHERE, para selecionar os registro por essa coluna?

Tags: array, postgresql, select

Tenho duas TABELA . **TAB1** e **TAB2**

**TAB1** tenho a coluna GRUPOS = {11, 15, 13, 20}

**TAB2** tenho a coluna:

REG1 GRUPOS = {11, 8, 15}

REG2 GRUPOS = {21, 5, 7}

REG3 GRUPOS = {1, 13, 21}

Fazer um **SELECT** usando a coluna da tabela **TAB1** [GRUPOS] que retorne : **REG1** e **REG3** da **TAB2**

Grato

Comment: Para evitar suposições descreva qual a condição deve ser atendida para constar do resultado desejado. Na TAB2 você tem 3 diferentes colunas, nomeadas REG1, REG2 e REG3, ou estas são diferentes linhas da mesma coluna?

Comment: Desculpe.. são três linhas.! TAB2 tem três linhas e deve retorna as linhas que na coluna grupo tenha algum código em comum com GRUPO da TAB1

Answer (score 0):

Se em ambas as tabelas você tem um campo chamado GRUPOS e deseja saber quais as linhas cujo campo GRUPOS tem elemento(s) em comum então utilize o operador && (overlap):

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 INNER JOIN tab2 ON (tab1.grupos && tab2.grupos);
```

Comment: Maravilha funcionou!! Obrigado